# .NET MAUI database connection works fine on emulator but getting error when app is installed in physical device

Tags: .net, sql-server, maui

I'm developing an Android app using .NET MAUI and directly connected my database to the app. I know this isn't the best practice, but I'm doing this just for testing. Anyways, this app I'm developing and the database connection is working fine on Windows (working on other machines too) and Android emu but when publishing the apk and install it to my physical Android phone I'm getting this error:

> TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

and sometimes this error is also showing

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught

but most of the time the error 40 is the error. So now I'm getting confused.

I checked these:

- TCP/IP and VIA is Enabled
- Allow remote connections to this server is checked.

I also tried to set the **ConnectionTimeout** to 120 in the connection string.

Comment: You're missing a lot of details. Where is the SQL Server instance installed? Is that location available to your Android device? How are you connecting to it?

Comment: We're using Azure cloud for the database, actually we already have a asp.net web app in production and I just copied the connection string from the asp.net to .net maui. I tried accessing the web app from my phone and it works (Db connection is okay). So I'm pretty sure my android phone can connect to the database.

Comment: Is it likely that Azure firewalls allow connections from your ASP.NET web app and your office network, but not from the mobile operator on which your Android device would be using?

Comment: I used the phone's mobile data to access our ASP.NET web app.

Comment: Yup but that does not mean you're talking to the DB directly, you're talking to the ASP.NET app which talks to the DB on your behalf. That is a different scenario.

Comment: Generally SQL dbs will not accept connections from any random IP -that is a terrible security risk.  If you want to override this behavior you’ll need to modify the settings of the DB in Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I created a web Api and host it on App Service in Azure and now my mobile app works fine. Thanks for the responses, everyone!